# How to save data between conversation in Dialogflow?

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

I don't understand how you're supposed to save data.
I tried using

```
let conv = agent.conv()
conv.data.data1=mydata //to save
mydata = conv.data.data1 //to load
agent.add(conv)
```

but it crash my app.
I saw that you could put info in

```
var token = JSON.stringify(request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.conversation.conversationToken);
```

but how do you put data in conversationToken in the response?

What is your method? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Use the output context to save parameters

```
{  
  "fulfillmentText":"This is a text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages":[  ],
  "source":"example.com",
  "payload":{  
    "google":{  },
    "facebook":{  },
    "slack":{  }
  },
  "outputContexts":[  
    {  
      "name":"<Context Name>",
      "lifespanCount":5,
      "parameters":{  
        "<param name>":"<param value>"
      }
    }
  ],
  "followupEventInput":{  }
}
```

If you are using [NodeJS client](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs)

You can save context with parameters like

```
let param1 = [];
let param2 = {};
let ctx = {'name': '<context name>', 'lifespan': 5, 'parameters': {'param1':param1, 'param2': param2}};
agent.setContext(ctx);
```

and get it like

```
let params = agent.getContext("<context name>").parameters;
let param1 = params.param1;
let param2 = params.param2;
```

You can store arrays, JSON obj but there is a limit to the total payload the response can save. check for more details [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response). For large data, use DB.

Also, if you are using standalone actions-on-google, then you can simply add key-value pair to the data object. See the [link](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/best-practices) where they are storing a count

Comment: Thanks ! But does it work with a lot of data ? I want to store some objects, 1 of them is an array of object, which itself contains other object. With a JSON ? I don't really know how to use it

Comment: I have updated answer. You can save arrays JSON till a limit. If you require very large data then use DB

Comment: And this parameter we are saving in contexts will be lost after the lifespan of context, right?

Comment: How can we save data throughout one conversation, just like `conv.data` in case of `actions-on-google` `conversation` object?

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to mark those parameters as required and use slot filling, that will automatically generate your output contexts during fulfillment. You can see this through a basic sample here: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-slot-filling-nodejs