# Sending parameter value from one intent to anothet and assign it to parameter

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have two intents - **serviceQuote** and **gotCar**

In **serviceQuote** intent, user will input 3 parameters - **carModel**, **carPrice** and **buyDate**. And he will receive a quotation according to parameter values.

In **gotCar** user can say `i just bought lamborghini`.
Dialogflow will get **carModel** and fire up event of **serviceQuote**. I want to send this **carModel** value along with and assign it to **serviceQuote** parameter **carModel** without prompting to the user.

Please note that question to ask **carModel** is first in the **serviceQuote** intent design and **all 3 parameters are marked as required**.

I have tried to invoke the event and send parameter value along with it. Intent is triggered but parameter value is not being assigned and it is asking the user again for car model.

```
'followupEventInput' : {
    "parameters": {
        "carModel": "aston martin",
    },
    'name' : 'e_serviceQuote',
}
```

What am I missing? How to achieve it.
I am using **DialogFlow v2**.

**Edit:** I tried to enter `#e_serviceQuote.carModel` as value of parameter, but Dialogflow console is not allowing me to enter it.

[image: car]

Answer (score 6):

You need to configure `#e_serviceQuote.carModel` in the `Default Value` for that parameter. That way, it'll be pre-filled with the value from that input context, or be empty if the context does not exist (or if the context exists but it doesn't contain that parameter).

[image: Mouse hover on the parameter row]

Then, set `#e_serviceQuote.carModel` as default value (in my example, it's `#appointment.date`)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You just need to assign the value of the followupEvent *carModel* parameter to the intent's *carModel* parameter. This means, in your *Action and parameters* table of the *serviceQuote* intent, the value of the *carModel* parameter has to be *#e_serviceQuote.carModel*.
[image: Dialogflow intent]

Comment: i have tried this, but console is not allowing me to enter anything other than `$carModel` and `$carModel.original`. I have updated question with screenshot as well.

Comment: It is not shown in the autocomplete, but I have used it and it works. I believe Dialogflow does not show these options in the autocomplete because event parameters are set in the fulfillment code, and there is no way to detect their names.

Comment: actually it is coming by default, i am not able to edit it or delete it. only after clicking on it, it is giving me those two options.

Comment: I guess you cannot set a parameter's value both using user says and event parameters... As a workaround you can create a new parameter `carModel_Event`, that gets its value from the event, and apply in your fulfillment some kind of priority if somehow both parameters have a valid value

Comment: but `carModel` is still set as **required** so it will prompt the user. :(

Comment: What about trying slot-filling? As [this section](https://dialogflow.com/docs/concepts/slot-filling#parameter_values_from_contexts) of the documentation says, you can set the `carModel` parameter value to $carModel, and set the default value to #e_serviceQuote.carModel, so if you don't get the value from the user query, it gets it from the event.

Comment: that will also won't work because slot filling will trigger when first slot is filled, and this slot is already the first slot. deadlock :P

Comment: Thanks. It just works. However, can I know the maximum number of Parameters that can be passed from one intent to another?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fulfilment, then you may save the parameters in the contexts. Check [my answer here for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878)

Comment: actuall i am able to send and retrieve data from contexts, my use case is different. if intent is called from another intent, then it should fill up a parameter value and not prompt the user.

Comment: as a workaround, i will make one more intent, call it and put same action.