# Save selected option of the list shown in Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using the [List rich response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses) in my assistant action and what I want is to save the option selected by user on the front end only.I am using Firebase as my backend server but I don't want this user selected option to store in firebase but it should get persisted across messages just like contexts.

What are the probable options to implement this?

Also, I found this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#json) where we can save the data in conversation, so can I use this feature? In which scenarios can we use this?

Thanks

Comment: The normal solution for this would be a context, is there any reason why you can't use this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have found the documentation on saving data. Do you have a question that isn't answered in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can save in parameters using context or in data if using only action-on-google client.
See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878)