# DIALOGFLOW! How to create a followup intent that is provoked when 3 previous intents have been answered in a certain way?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I’m working on a memory game with multiple levels on Dialogflow. Each correctly guessed question is a separate intent and all 3 questions need to be answered correctly to proceed to the next level. How do I create the game so that the second level (which will be the follow up intent) is only provoked when all 3 questions from the 1st level are answered correctly? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Do you have code you can post that shows the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Instead of having the followup intent, you can maintain a counter in a parameter (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878) for storing parameters).
- Enable webhook in all the intents.
- Whenever a question is answered, check the validity and if correct increment the counter.
- When the counter reaches 3, you can respond back with the response of your choice.

If you want to go by your way then, after answering 3 question correctly you will need to [generate an event](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events) dynamically via webhook. And the fourth intent should be triggered using that event.

Comment: Thanks so much Abhinav!

Comment: Happy to help you :)