# Unable to store a list of variables for a next round of conversation in Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I really would love to be able to store an array with string variables obtained during conversation to retrieve during a next turn of conversation, in order to be able to compare an old an a new array.
Even when I add all items of an array to a new array specifically, it will be wiped out in the next round of conversation.

Thanks.

This is my current function:

```
function game(agent, parameters) {
    var suitcase = agent.parameters.objecten;
    var oldsuitcase = agent.parameters.oldsuitcase;
    if (suitcase.length > 1) {
        if (suitcase.splice(-1,1) != oldsuitcase) {
            agent.add('Helaas, je hebt niet de juiste objecten genoemd. Ik heb gewonnen! Volgende keer beter.');
            return;
        }
    }
    var items = [ "paspoort", "visum", "bankpas", "creditcard", "geld", "adressenlijst", "rijbewijs", "toiletspullen", "zonnebrandcrème", "shampo", "douchegel", "tandenstokers", "badlaken", "washandje", "handdoek", "deodorant", "maandverband", "nagelschaar", "tandenborstel", "tandpasta", "zakdoeken", "paracetamol", "medicijnen", "neusdruppels", "pleisters", "klamboe", "slippers", "broek", "rok", "jurk", "blouse", "shirt", "sokken", "onderbroek", "badpak", "zwembroek", "schoenen", "sandalen", "waterschoenen", "pet", "hoed", "zonnebril", "pyjama", "bril", "lenzenvloeistof", "horloge", "portemonnee", "brillenkoker", "tas", "sleutels", "boek", "tijdschrift", "spel", "pen", "zaklamp", "speelgoed", "zakmes", "schrijfpapier", "telefoon", "telefoonlader", "tablet", "camera", "reiswekker", "selfiestick", "reisgids", "chocola", "muggenlamp", "gitaar" ];
    var newitem = agent.parameters.objecten[0];
    while (suitcase.includes(newitem)) {
        newitem = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < suitcase.length; i++) {
        oldsuitcase.push(suitcase[i]);
        }
    suitcase.push(newitem);
    oldsuitcase.push(newitem);
    agent.add(oldsuitcase);
    agent.add('Ik ga op vakantie en ik neem mee:' + suitcase);
    }
```

Comment: You could store it globally or in localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878). 
You can store it like

```
let param1 = [];
let param2 = {};
let ctx = {'name': '<context name>', 'lifespan': 5, 'parameters': {'param1':param1, 'param2': param2}};
agent.setContext(ctx);
```

and fetch it in other intent like

```
let params = agent.getContext("<context name>").parameters;
let param1 = params.param1;
let param2 = params.param2;
```

Play with the lifespan value to keep it valid in the session.

Comment: Happy to help you. If possible mark the answer for others to follow if facing a similar issue.