# Parse multiple context values in Dialogflow response

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to send parameter values of previos context in DialogFlow Responses. I know it can be done like `#context_name.parameter_name`.

Problem is in my intent, there are multiple contexts set like below:

[image: response]

I was hoping it would check which context is active in given 4 context and response accordingly, but it is taking randomly.
So sometimes response is correct (`Thanks for the details. Your info : Richard`) and sometimes wrong (`Thanks for the details. Your info : #intent1.given-name`).

Is there any workaround?
This is just example, there can be different context and different values.
And even if the context value is same but parameter value is different, we are facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Dialogflow to respond back to the user and not using a webhook.
If that is the case, the way you are using Text response, it will not help you. This will always give a random reply to the user. 
Better to use a webhook and extract your parameters in the code based on context and use them. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878) to use Context to save Parameters using NodeJS client and use it in webhook.

Comment: but i have read somewhere that from the list dialogflow will check the values and select the response... or something like that. i am not able to recall exactly. i was trying to search that. i have seen your other answer on how to use webhook, it was great,  but i wanted to check dialogflow functionality.

Comment: I am not sure about the values in the text responses, but whatever I have seen past 1 year, it comes out random. But I don't have any value attached to my Dialogflow responses. Only static responses. Do share when you find out if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still relevant but you can press `shift+enter` to add a new line in most integrations. That way you can respond with all your values in a single response block.