# How to store data in conversation using Dialogflow webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using dialogflow webhook and want to store data in conversation.

Below is what i understood from [dialogflow docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json)

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   response.send(JSON.stringify({
    "payload": {
        "google": {
          "expectUserResponse": true,
          "richResponse": {
            "items": [
              {
                "simpleResponse": {
                  "textToSpeech": "OKAY"
                }
              }
            ]
          }, 
          "conversationToken" : "count=1"
        }
      }
   }))
```

This does not work as the JSON from the next request does not have this stored value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878). 
In short use contexts to store parameters.

Use the output context to save parameters

```
{  
  "fulfillmentText":"This is a text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages":[  ],
  "source":"example.com",
  "payload":{  
    "google":{  },
    "facebook":{  },
    "slack":{  }
  },
  "outputContexts":[  
    {  
      "name":"<Context Name>",
      "lifespanCount":5,
      "parameters":{  
        "<param name>":"<param value>"
      }
    }
  ],
  "followupEventInput":{  }
}
```

Comment: What is the maximum value that i can use for lifespanCount ?

Comment: I have never used it for more than 4. By default, Dialogflow sets 5.

Comment: We've used `250` without issue for last-longing contextes. The max value isn't an issue anyway, because you can refresh the value anytime, so you can set a context to 5 lifespan and refresh it in all webhook calls for instance, it'll never die.

Comment: And this parameter we are saving in contexts will be lost after the lifespan of context, right?
How can we save data throughout one conversation, just like `conv.data` in case of `actions-on-google` `conversation` object?

Comment: create a context that will not be used in intent calling and set the a large lifespan