# Passing user provided value from one intent to other intent in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Team,
In DialogFlow, I getting a value from the user in intent A; (let's say it's the employee ID).
In next Intent B, I want to use the Employee ID (collected in previous intent A) and provide a response and execute a webhook.

I am able to collect the value in Intent A and display in same intent. When tried to pass it to another Intent, I am failing miserably.

Appreciate ayny help in this regard.

Tnx
Sathiya

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use contexts to store the parameters and access these parameters through the context in the other intent.

Check out my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878)

```
{  
  "fulfillmentText":"This is a text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages":[  ],
  "source":"example.com",
  "payload":{  
    "google":{  },
    "facebook":{  },
    "slack":{  }
  },
  "outputContexts":[  
    {  
      "name":"<Context Name>",
      "lifespanCount":5,
      "parameters":{  
        "<param name>":"<param value>"
      }
    }
  ],
  "followupEventInput":{  }
}
```

from NodeJS code
save in first Intent

```
let param1 = [];
let param2 = {};
let ctx = {'name': '<context name>', 'lifespan': 5, 'parameters': {'param1':param1, 'param2': param2}};
agent.setContext(ctx);
```

Access in other Intent as

```
let params = agent.getContext("<context name>").parameters;
let param1 = params.param1;
let param2 = params.param2;
```

Comment: managed to do that with fulfillment / code.

but how to do it using just the dialogflow interface?

I'm using context output / input (same name) but the values are not been passed