# How to handle Fallback Loop in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

There are two loops here:

1. Re-prompt from DialogFlow when user is not entering correct value for **slot**
   eg.

   > Bot: What is color of your car?
   >   User: potato
   >   Bot: What is color of your car?
   >   User: tomato
   >   Bot: What is color of your car?
   >   ...
2. Getting fallback intent replies from DialogFlow
   eg.

   > Bot: What is your car brand?
   >   User: red
   >   Bot: Sorry, could you rephrase.
   >   User: red red
   >   Bot: I did not understand, could you say it again.
   >   ...

How to come out of these scenarios? There is no provision of setting number of re-prompts.

Thanks to @Abhinav, I got one approach of using `outputContexts` to solve this issue, however I am getting many cases to get this working as described in below pic:
[image]

But I am getting confused whether I should increment the counter or decrement it. As output contexts also gets decrement with every call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to maintain that by yourself. For Action on Google you can look into following example https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts

For Dialogflow:

- Create a parameter, "re-prompt"
- Check it in fallback intents.
- increment it in fallback.
- reset or decrement it in other intents.
- if it is greater than 2, you may exit the conversation by letting the user know that you are unable to process at this time.

Comment: but fallback intents do not support parameters... how to add it in fallback?

Comment: Use context to pass parameters in Dialoflow. Do not get confused with Entity/Parameters :)

Comment: You need to maintain a flag in your context. I am not understanding what do you meant by Payload here.

Comment: could you show some code, it will be more clear. as per my current understanding you are setting `outputContext` in webhook when fallback is hit, and incrementing it in subsequent fallback hits.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878