# How to pass params from one intent to another dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

how does one pass the params from a intent in the fulfillment editor to another followup intent.

Here is my code

```
    // original intent
    // the params defined here are the ones I want to pass to the app.intent below.

    app.intent('Book Appointment', (conv, params) => {

            // the params that i want to access in the next intent
            const date = params['date'];
            const time = params['time'];
            const firstName = params['given-name'];
            const email = params['email'];

            // what i dont get is what to put in here is it
            // how am i formatting this?
            const parameters = {'date':params.date,}

            // is the 'welcome-context' replaced with this one from the JSON? like so?
```

[image]

```
            conv.contexts.set('projects/myproject-120c2/agent/sessions/c2c1c9e0-2ccf-0cf0-d7ce-e52561d44de3/contexts/bookappointment-followup"', 5, parameters);

// or is it

conv.contexts.set('bookappointment-followup', 5, parameters); // ??

// like it is in Dialogflow
```

[image]

```
    })


    // follow-up intent
    app.intent('Book Appointment - yes', (conv, params) => {
        // this is where I want to access the ones above


        // then im accessing them like this?
        const conv.contexts.get('bookappointment-followup').parameters['whatever it is above'];

        })
```

The variables in the email return undefined. I reckon it's something to do with the contexts but I dont know if its the same code like #book.appointment.follow.date etc.

Help is appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878)

Use the output context to save parameters

```
{  
  "fulfillmentText":"This is a text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages":[  ],
  "source":"example.com",
  "payload":{  
    "google":{  },
    "facebook":{  },
    "slack":{  }
  },
  "outputContexts":[  
    {  
      "name":"<Context Name>",
      "lifespanCount":5,
      "parameters":{  
        "<param name>":"<param value>"
      }
    }
  ],
  "followupEventInput":{  }
}
```

If you are using [NodeJS client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878)

You can save context with parameters like

```
let param1 = [];
let param2 = {};
let ctx = {'name': '<context name>', 'lifespan': 5, 'parameters': {'param1':param1, 'param2': param2}};
agent.setContext(ctx);
```

and get it like

```
let params = agent.getContext("<context name>").parameters;
let param1 = params.param1;
let param2 = params.param2;
```

If using `conv`, you may also try like this:

```
app.intent('<INTENT>', conv => {
  conv.ask('<RESPONSE>');
  const parameters = {'param1':param1, 'param2': param2}};
  conv.contexts.set('welcome-context', 5, parameters);
});
```

and access it like [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration) :

```
const conv.contexts.get(<context>).parameters[<param>];
```

If via `context` doesn't work, you may try with `data` like

```
conv.data.someProperty = 'someValue'
```

as stated [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#contexts)

Comment: So like this? I'm confused. `// follow-up intent
app.intent('Book Appointment - yes', (conv, params) => {
    
    const parameters = {'given-name':''};
    conv.contexts.set('bookappointment-followup', 1, parameters);
    const contexts = conv.contexts;
    
    let firstName = params.given-name; 
    
    conv.ask(`hello ${firstName}`);
    
})`

Comment: Also I'm using the inline editor and using conv. Like this

`app.intent('intent-name', (conv, params) => {})`

Comment: const contexts = conv.contexts;  should be used in other contexts to extract the stored value.

Comment: And using `const contexts = conv.contexts` how do I extract the value? Whats the code?

Comment: conv.contexts.get('welcome-context').parameters['param1'] will give you param1

Comment: It's returning 'undefined'

Comment: please check the documentation. do debugging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180927/discussion-between-slappedprogrammer-and-abhinav-tyagi).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this worked.

```
const firstName = conv.contexts.get('bookappointment-followup').parameters['given-name'];
```

:)

Comment: if that worked you can accept and upvote the answer. That will help others :)