# Dialogflow V2 and passing parameters in request body to webhook

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, grpc

I am trying to pass parameters to an intent and I am calling the intent by it's Event name.

I understand that the parameters object has to be converted from a Json to a Struct, but for some reason the parameters are not passing. What am I doing wrong?

**Please note** I had to copy and paste the 'structjson.js' provided by Google into the same directory as my index.js because I am exporting to Firebase Functions, and I had to place some constants inside of certain functions within the structjson.js so I could export those functions to use in my index.js file.

- **Expected response from Dialogflow:** *'Your user ID is: 00000001'*
- **Actual response from Dialogflow:** *'Your user ID is: ${n_digit}'*

**Request to Dialogflow Code**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as dialogflow from 'dialogflow';
// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const register = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    // Instantiates a session client
    const projectId = [MY_PROJECT_ID];
    const sessionId = '123456789';
    const languageCode = 'en-US';
    let config = {
            credentials: {
                private_key: [MY_PRIVATE_KEY],
                client_email: [MY_CLIENT_EMAIL]
            }
        }
    const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(config);

    // The path to identify the agent that owns the created intent.
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

    var structjson = require('./structjson')

    // The text query request.
    const req = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryParams: {
        "resetContexts": true,
    },
    queryInput: {
      event: {
        name: 'init',
        parameters: structjson.jsonToStructProto({userID: '00000001'}),
        languageCode: languageCode,
      },
    },
    };

    sessionClient
    .detectIntent(req)
    .then((responses) => {
      const result = responses[0].queryResult;
      response.send(result.fulfillmentText);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
})
```

**structjson.js**

```
module.exports.jsonToStructProto = function jsonToStructProto(json) {
    var structjson = require('./structjson')
      const fields = {};
      for (const k in json) {
        fields[k] = structjson.jsonValueToProto(json[k]);
      }

      return {fields};
    }

    module.exports.jsonValueToProto = function jsonValueToProto(value) {
      const valueProto = {};
      const JSON_SIMPLE_TYPE_TO_PROTO_KIND_MAP = {
        [typeof 0]: 'numberValue',
        [typeof '']: 'stringValue',
        [typeof false]: 'boolValue',
      };

      if (value === null) {
        valueProto.kind = 'nullValue';
        valueProto.nullValue = 'NULL_VALUE';
      } else if (value instanceof Array) {
        valueProto.kind = 'listValue';
        valueProto.listValue = {values: value.map(jsonValueToProto)};
      } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
        valueProto.kind = 'structValue';
        valueProto.structValue = jsonToStructProto(value);
      } else if (typeof value in JSON_SIMPLE_TYPE_TO_PROTO_KIND_MAP) {
        const kind = JSON_SIMPLE_TYPE_TO_PROTO_KIND_MAP[typeof value];
        valueProto.kind = kind;
        valueProto[kind] = value;
      } else {
        console.warn('Unsupported value type ', typeof value);
      }
      return valueProto;
    }

    module.exports.structProtoToJson = function structProtoToJson(proto) {
      if (!proto || !proto.fields) {
        return {};
      }
      const json = {};
      for (const k in proto.fields) {
        json[k] = valueProtoToJson(proto.fields[k]);
      }
      return json;
    }

    module.exports.valueProtoToJson = function valueProtoToJson(proto) {

        const JSON_SIMPLE_VALUE_KINDS = new Set([
          'numberValue',
          'stringValue',
          'boolValue',
        ]);

      if (!proto || !proto.kind) {
        return null;
      }

      if (JSON_SIMPLE_VALUE_KINDS.has(proto.kind)) {
        return proto[proto.kind];
      } else if (proto.kind === 'nullValue') {
        return null;
      } else if (proto.kind === 'listValue') {
        if (!proto.listValue || !proto.listValue.values) {
          console.warn('Invalid JSON list value proto: ', JSON.stringify(proto));
        }
        return proto.listValue.values.map(valueProtoToJson);
      } else if (proto.kind === 'structValue') {
        return structProtoToJson(proto.structValue);
      } else {
        console.warn('Unsupported JSON value proto kind: ', proto.kind);
        return null;
      }
    }
```

**Dialogflow webhook**

```
function receiveParams (agent) {
    const parameter = request.body.queryResult.parameters;
     const n_digit = parameter.userID;
     agent.add('Your user ID is: ${n_digit}');
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('init', receiveParams);  
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would like to make a note that the fact that you have to use a struct object in that parameter is unrelated to gRPC. It is simply how the API is defined. The only thing that is really specific to gRPC here is the automatic conversion from plain JS objects to the protobuf messages that the API uses.

Comment: Nice one! Edited, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send parameters like

```
{  
  "fulfillmentText":"This is a text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages":[  ],
  "source":"example.com",
  "payload":{  
    "google":{  },
    "facebook":{  },
    "slack":{  }
  },
  "outputContexts":[  
    {  
      "name":"<Context Name>",
      "lifespanCount":5,
      "parameters":{  
        "<param name>":"<param value>"
      }
    }
  ],
  "followupEventInput":{  }
}
```

Using [NodeJS client](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) you can save params like

```
let param1 = [];
let param2 = {};
let ctx = {'name': '<context name>', 'lifespan': 5, 'parameters': {'param1':param1, 'param2': param2}};
agent.setContext(ctx);
```

and access these params like

```
let params = agent.getContext("<context name>").parameters;
let param1 = params.param1;
let param2 = params.param2;
```

Check out my [complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878).

Comment: Is this to send context parameters from a client server to the agent?

Comment: this is to save parameters to be used in subsequent conversation. This can be accessed from both clients as well as in server till the context is alive.

Comment: Ah! I see, sorry in the post I should have gave more context. The NodeJS library you sent is for the agent side (fulfillment webhook.) I am only trying to inject parameters in the payload sent from my web server to the Dialogflow agent. I'm not missing something am I? Thank you for your help and responses so far.

Comment: you can inject the parameters in the JSON as shown above :)

Comment: ? But I am using a session client object from the NodeJS client library, but the setContext method is a method from the fulfillment library not the client library

Comment: Okay I get it now, I can access these active contexts with my webhook in what you sent. I can also use #context_name.key in the ctx object I create to respond with it in my Dialogflow agent. Thank you!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you can upvote and mark it as answer for others to follow.

Comment: The only problem is, when I use "detectIntent()" after setting the context parameters right after the event call I can't use the context parameters in the same session ID. Any ideas?

Comment: Like when I use #context_name.key in my other intent responses it doesn't show up.

Comment: Now we can use `let params = agent.originalRequest.parameters;` according to [this](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client) too, found out this works pretty well. Even when adding context params in the request this will pop up under the originalRequest child. Thank you for helping me get to this point, @Abhinav Tyagi.